# Newly-assignmed variables not showing up in Spyder's variable explorer

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, spyder

I'm writing Python on Spyder. Please see my code below:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.io.excel.read_excel('Data.xls')
CMT_column = data['CMT']
```

"data" contains a column called "CMT." What I'm trying to do is create a variable called "CMT_column" that contains the values of the "CMT" column.

Here's the problem. After I run the code, only "data" appears in the variable explorer. "CMT_column" is not there. But if I call "CMT_column" in the IPython console, it shows the values of "CMT" as expected. So I guess the variable has been created after all, but why is it not visible in the variable explore?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: does it show up if you define a third, meaningless variable (like `xzy = None`)

Comment: @PaulH If I do xyz = None, it doesn't show up. If I do xyz = 1, it shows up.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Go to Variable explorer window.

Then you have options button right hand side.

Click on it,Untick the option Exclude all uppercase preferences as shown in image.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Spyder's variable explorer does not like variables with upper case: try rewriting CMT_ as cmt_.

Answer (score 0):

I just added the below library then it works

from IPython.display import display

display()