# scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix not showing in variable explorer

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, ipython, spyder

This question is not the duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31526983/newly-assignmed-variables-not-showing-up-in-spyders-variable-explorer), because only scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix type is not showing in variable explorer whereas any other code when executed shows successfully in variable explorer.

I tried restarting both Ipython kernel as well as Spyder along with Anaconda.

```py
In [1]:from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
In [2]:tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words = 'english',ngram_range = (1,2),min_df = 5,sublinear_tf = True)
In [3]:fea = tfidf.fit_transform(df['text']) #this returns a scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix type
In [4]:type(fea)
Out[4]:scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
In [5]:a_str = "qwertyuiop" #this shows in variable explorer
```

I can use the fea variable normally but I don't see it in variable explorer.

**Edit:**

looking at current Ipyhton active variables it shows fea as an variable.

```
In [6]:print(dir())
Out [6]:['TfidfVectorizer','fea','a_str','tfidf','df']
```

Comment: `fea` is a variable, whose `type` is `csr_matrix`.  That is not a variable in your code.  The package that defines this class was probably imported by `sklearn`, and doesn't show up independently in the IDE's `explorer`.

Comment: @hpaulj could you be more clearer(or maybe provide a link), I didn't get what you meant

Comment: Is `fea` showing?

Comment: no it is not @hpaulj

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please go to Options menu of the Variable Explorer (the one with the cog icon on its top right) and deselect the option called `Exclude unsupported data types`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Carlos commented above it worked, I needed to deselect the `Exclude unsupported data types` option in spyder's variable explorer.